# Combobox query override

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

How to return with query value and current combobox name?
I have combobox with remote store.

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    fieldLabel: 'Some label',
    editable: false,
    name: 'my_combo',
    matchFieldWidth: false,
    displayField: 'foo',
    mode: 'remote',
    store: 'fooStore',
    valueField: 'foo2'
}
```

At the moment it returns url with params

```
query=my%20search
page=1
start=0
limit=25
```

How to return

```
query=[{'my_combo':'my search'}]
page=1
start=0
limit=25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There maybe a less intrusive way to do what you need, but here is how I solved a similar request to intercept and override the query sent to server:

Custom field definition that extends from Ext.form.field.ComboBox

```
initComponent:function () {
    this.on({
        beforequery:function(queryEvent){
            if (queryEvent.query)     {
                //uppercase typed in value
                queryEvent.query = queryEvent.query.toUpperCase().replace(" ","","g"); //.trim(); --errors out in IE9 compat mode
                queryEvent.combo.setValue(queryEvent.query);
            }
            Ext.Ajax.abortAll(); //cancel any previous requests
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I solved it thru `listeners` with `'beforequery':function(queryevent)...` but point is the same.